# Reading a text file and assigning its content to different variables in vb 6

Tags: text, vb6

I am currently trying to make a RPG game. I have how the save game function works, but I cannot figure out how to make the load function work.  I am trying to assign a text files content to different variables but when I look up how, I always find people are setting the content of the text files to a single variables when I am trying to assign it to 6 different variables.  Is there a way for me to do this, or do I have to store each of them into different text files?

```
nFileNum = FreeFile

' Open a text file for input. inputbox returns the path to read the file
Open "C:\DaggerFall\CharacterInformation.txt" For Input As nFileNum

lLineCount = 1

' Read the contents of the file
Do While Not EOF(nFileNum)
    Line Input #nFileNum, sNextLine
    sNextLine = sNextLine & vbCrLf
    sText = sText & sNextLine
Loop

Text1.Text = sText

' Close the file
Close nFileNum
```

Comment: You have tagged this question `vb.net` but your title says "vb 6".  Which is it?  Also, what have you actually tried?

Comment: It is vb6, and I have tried

Comment: nFileNum = FreeFile
' Open a text file for input. inputbox returns the path to read the file
Open "C:\DaggerFall\CharacterInformation.txt" For Input As nFileNum
lLineCount = 1
' Read the contents of the file
Do While Not EOF(nFileNum)
   Line Input #nFileNum, sNextLine
   sNextLine = sNextLine & vbCrLf
   sText = sText & sNextLine
   
Loop
Text1.Text = sText
' Close the file
Close nFileNum

Comment: I've copied your code to your question and formatted it so it's readable.  I don't use VB6 so this is where I get off.

Comment: Ok thank you for helping me with making it easier to read.

Comment: you are reading all data from the file, but which parts of the data do you want to assign to which variables? your code is ok, now you have to think about which parts of the data you need, and how those parts are separated .. please post a sample of the data and how it is built up

Answer (score 0):

You read in the data correctly, now you have to split the data according to the different values on a line

for example i created the following file

```
a 16 16 10 4 4
b 4 8 6 16 16
c 4 10 16 6 14
```

This file consist of a line per character, and each line consists of 6 columns : name, str, con, dex, wis, int stats separated by a space between the stats

i created a test project which reads in the file, stores the data and displays the names in a listbox
when you click on a name in the listbox, then the stats belonging to that name are shows in a messagebox

```
'1 form with:
'  1 command button: name=Command1
'  1 listbox control: name=List1
Option Explicit

'the type containing all stats
Private Type CharInfo
  strName As String
  intStr As Integer
  intCon As Integer
  intDex As Integer
  intWis As Integer
  intInt As Integer
End Type

'form level variable to store all the data
Private mudtChar() As CharInfo

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim intLine As Integer, intCount As Integer
  Dim intFile As Integer
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strData As String
  Dim strLine() As String, strPart() As String
  'clear the listbox
  List1.Clear
  'read the whole file into 1 string variable
  strFile = "c:\temp\file.txt"
  intFile = FreeFile
  Open strFile For Input As #intFile
    strData = Input(LOF(intFile), intFile)
  Close #intFile
  'split the data on strings per line
  strLine = Split(strData, vbCrLf)
  'count the lines to find out how many character names there are in the file
  intCount = UBound(strLine)
  'resize the storage to contain all the data
  ReDim mudtChar(intCount) As CharInfo
  'loop through all line to write the character data into the storage variable
  For intLine = 0 To intCount
    strPart = Split(strLine(intLine), " ")
    With mudtChar(intLine)
      .strName = strPart(0)
      List1.AddItem .strName 'show the name in the listbox
      .intStr = Val(strPart(1))
      .intCon = Val(strPart(2))
      .intDex = Val(strPart(3))
      .intWis = Val(strPart(4))
      .intInt = Val(strPart(5))
    End With 'mudtChar(intLine)
  Next intLine
End Sub

Private Sub List1_Click()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Dim strShow As String
  'find the index which was clicked
  intIndex = List1.ListIndex
  With mudtChar(intIndex)
    'build the data which you want to show
    strShow = .strName
    strShow = strShow & vbCrLf & "Str : " & CStr(.intStr)
    strShow = strShow & vbCrLf & "Con : " & CStr(.intCon)
    strShow = strShow & vbCrLf & "Dex : " & CStr(.intDex)
    strShow = strShow & vbCrLf & "Wis : " & CStr(.intWis)
    strShow = strShow & vbCrLf & "Int : " & CStr(.intInt)
    'show the data
    MsgBox strShow, vbInformation, .strName
  End With 'mudtChar(intIndex)
End Sub
```

I hope this will explain how you can split the data from a file

Answer (score -1):

You are using old file functions. New ones are a lot easier.

This is vbscript code and is pasteable into VB6. However it's late bound (uses `set x = createobject("objectname")` instead `set x = new objectname`) and untyped (no `as string`). For speed reasons you want to use early (add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`) binding and type your variables.

```
'Create the object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Turn on programmer error handler
On Error Resume Next

'Open a file - 1 means for reading, true means create if it doesn't exist, 0 means ANSI
Set myfile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\windows\win.ini", 1, true 0)

'test for errors
If err.num <> 0 then
    'Check here for specific problems
    If err.num = 53 then
        'Decide what to do if user deleted file
        err.clear
    Else
        'Decide to do an err.raise and crash.
        err.Raise(err.num, "FSO Object")
        Exit (Sub or Function - whichever)
    End If
End If

'Read the file all at once. `Read` does bytes and `ReadLine` does lines.
FileContents = myfile.ReadAll

'Turn on vbscript error handling    
On Error Goto 0

'Print it
msgbox FileContents

'If you need to close it (it will close as soon as you hit an `End Sub` automatically).
Set myfile = Nothing

'If you need to close the fso object - you are finished with all file operations (it will close as soon as you hit an `End Sub` automatically).
Set fso = Nothing
```

Once in a string you can loop through (`Instr`), use `Split` to turn it into an array. Or many other things.

Comment: why would using the FileSystemObject be easier than the old file functions, as you state?

Comment: Try HelpIntroduction to the File System Object Model


A new feature for Visual Basic is the File System Object (FSO) object model, which provides an object-based tool for working with folders and files. This allows you to use the familiar object.method syntax with a rich set of properties, methods, and events to process folders and files, in addition to using the traditional Visual Basic statements and commands.

Comment: that doesnt mean that it is easier than the old standard methods